# TextBlock + RichTextBox to clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the contents of dynamically created TextBlock and dynamically created RichTextboxes (they sit side by side) into the clipboard in c# + wpf, however, I'm not able to do so.  I've search all over google to no avail, the latest code I came up with is

```
StringBuilder clipboard = new StringBuilder();
        String rtb = scrlPanel.Children.OfType<RichTextBox>().ToString();
        //List<RichTextBox> rtb = scrlPanel.Children.OfType<RichTextBox>().;

        foreach(TextBlock txtb in scrlPanel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
        {
            clipboard.Append(txtb.Text + " " + "::" + Environment.NewLine + rtb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        }
        Clipboard.SetText(clipboard.ToString());
```

but it doesn't work, the codes copies the TextBlocks just fine but the RichTextBoxes content display" "System.Linq.Enumerable+d__aa`1[System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox]"

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the from the ToString() - method, which by default shows the typename.

You should do it like this:

StringBuilder clipboard = new StringBuilder();

```
    List<RichTextBox> rtbs = scrlPanel.Children.OfType<RichTextBox>().ToList();
    List<TextBlock> texts = scrlPanel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().ToList();

    foreach(TextBlock txtb in texts)
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = rtbs[texts.indexOf(txtb)];
        string rtbtext = new TextRange(rtb .Document.ContentStart, rtb .Document.ContentEnd).Text; 
        clipboard.Append(txtb.Text + " " + "::" + Environment.NewLine + rtbtext + Environment.NewLine);

    }
    Clipboard.SetText(clipboard.ToString());
```

That is, if you just as many TextBoxes as RichTextBoxes and they have the same order.

PD: There's probably better ways of doing this, but this would be a quick fix.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, you are right, there are as many RichTextBoxes as there are TextBlocks - I've tried trying to get a .Text property for a richtextbox but it does come up and using .ToString() just gives me the typename

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with Windows Forms one. I'll update my answer

Comment: I got it!, I tried using a TextRange with List<RichTextBox>...... but it would not accept the rtb.Document - it just would not give me the option but with your help I've managed to add a TextRange and just implement it on the clipboard code like shown..

foreach (TextBlock txtb in texts)
{
  RichTextBox rtb = rtbs[texts.IndexOf(txtb)];
  TextRange txtRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
  clipboard.Append(txtb.Text + " " + "::" + Environment.NewLine + txtRange.Text.TrimEnd() + Environment.NewLine);
}